Какой обход должен использоваться в алгоритме Белмана Форда?
обойти граф нужно V-1 кол-во раз но какой обход использовать ? В глубину,в ширину или очередь с приоритетом строить? И нужно ли помечать вершину как пройденная или непройденная?

Ничего из перечисленного. Вам же советовали прочитать описание. Алгоритм не использует обход графа в обычном смысле.
